# For loop through class

Tags: python, for-loop

```
import v1.bot.main
import v2.bot.main

for i in ['v1', 'v2]:
    # I want the for loop to do something like i.bot.main()
    
    # Like
    # v1.bot.main()
    # v2.bot.main()
```

**Is this possible?** I want to get rid of the writing of vX and want to put it into a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`as` keyword is important because import statement returns an object of type `<class 'module'>`. You'll be calling the `main()` function through the `module` object.

```
import v1.bot.main as v1
import v2.bot.main as v2

for i in ["v1", "v2"]:
    eval(f"{i}.main()")
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to add all the version instances of bot to a dictionary like:

```
global_bot_list = {1 : v1.bot(), 2: v2.bot()}
```

Then just do a for loop like this:

```
for bot in global_bot_list.items():
     bot.main()
```

If you want to make code completion work you should probably make an abstract base class for all your bots to inherit from that has the `main` method and change the signature of `global_bot_list` to: `global_bot_list: Dict[int, BotBase]` with `BotBase` being whatever name you chose to call the new base class.

By the way in order for this to work you will need to add an `__init__` method to each bot class and `main` needs to be an instance method that has `self` as its first parameter.